# ブラウザの戻るボタンで戻ったときにリロードする方法はありますか？

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

ブラウザの戻るボタンで戻った時、最新のページを読み込みたいのですが、可能でしょうか？
IE10または11でできればＯＫです。
以下のコードで試してみたのですが、うまくいきませんでした。よろしくお願いします！

```
<script>
<!--
window.onunload = function(){location.reload();}
-->
</script>
```

常に強制リロードで解決は出来ましたが却下されました。やはり「戻る」限定で行いたいです。

```
$(function(){
    if (window.name != "re_load") {
        location.reload();
        window.name = "re_load";
    }else{
        window.name = "";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScriptではなくサーバー側で戻る対象のページのHTTPヘッダーに

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
```

のように指定してキャッシュを無効化すべきだと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。HTMLのmetaタグで試してみましたが、うまくいきませんでした。HTML5で作られているのですが、HTML4にしてmetaタグを追加してみましたが、うまくいきませんでした。キャッシュの観点で調査してみます！

Comment: metaタグの無いhtmlがキャッシュされているだけでは・・・

Comment: metaはサーバー側をどうしてもいじれない場合に使える可能性があるという程度のつもりでした。回答で断定的に書いてしまったのは申し訳ないです。IE側のリファレンスでは明記されていませんが、W3Cの定義によると`http-equiv`は実質3,4種類しか許可されていないようです。

Answer (score 1):

PHP側のコントローラに以下のコードを追加したら解決しました。
ありがとうございます。

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

https://teratail.com/questions/91